# Discrete Math question; how many subsets of any size can be made from n?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say I have a box of 5 different lego people, and 3 sculptures I want to place them on. Each lego environment must get at least one person. How many ways can I arrange the lego people? (The order or specific placement on each sculpture doesn't matter or count as a different way to arrange them.)

I think this is asking "Given a set with N elements, how many ways can I make M sets out of it where the sets do not have to be of equal length but must be at least 1?" I'm looking for a formula that can be used on much larger numbers rather than a way to count it out by hand or chart.

Comment: Does each of the Lego people have to be used, or can some of them be left in the box?

Comment: This problem can be tackled with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).